# Route with dot (IP address) not found, returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-routing, lumen-5.4

I use `Lumen 5.4`.

This is how my route is setup:

```
$app->get('/ip/{ip}', GeoIpController::class . '@show');
```

The `{ip}` route parameter should be an IP address, with dots in it. However, it seems there is a problem when a route has dots in it.  It returns a 404 not found error.

I am aware I could pass the IP address in as a simple `GET` request parameter, but want the IP to be part of the URL and to be handled like a route parameter.

For testing purposes, I use `php -S localhost:8080 -t public` to serve the application.

Comment: From my experience with Laravel, I haven't seen a dot in a route parameter being an issue, however, I've also never started a route with `/`.  As far as I know, routes are relative from the prefix (or / if no prefix is set), so `ip/{ip}` is what you should use.  See if that fixes your 404.

Comment: I'm afraid this request never reaches Lumen and it's killed by server somehow.

Comment: So the problem isn't related to Lumen then?  What web server are you using?  Any errors?  Do you have it properly routed through your index.php?

Comment: base encode the ip and decode it in the controller

Comment: @Devon for testing purposes I use `php -S localhost:8080 -t public/` since Lumen hasn't got it's build-in server like Laravel. I didn't checked in on staging. There I have nginx.

Comment: @wujt use `php artisan serve`

Comment: @Devon as I said, Lumen hasn't got it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a limitation on PHP's built in server, not with Lumen (or Laravel, or Slim, or any other frameworks/apps with a router). You can view the [PHP bug report here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61286).

Basically, if the URL has a dot in the url after the script name, the built-in server treats the request as a static file request, and it never actually attempts to run through the application.

This request should work fine on a real web server (apache, nginx), but it will fail when run on PHP's built-in development web server.