# xampp php laravel routing with character . not working

Tags: php, laravel, apache, routes, xampp

I use an old laravel lumen 5.8 and tried to make a route like :

```
http://localhost:8001/url/api/v1
```

and its working fine, but when I want to make route like

```
http://localhost:8001/url/api/v1.0
```

its return some error, i think this is on xampp / apache / php  level
because when we input the wrong endpoint with env debug=true, laravel will return error as normally laravel error page. But this route return error like [image]

Comment: Show your route?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777274/can-urls-contain-dots-in-the-path-part

Comment: thankyou for the reference @devsead . i appreciate it

Comment: did you figure this out? if so please post an answer and accept

Answer (score 0):

[as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077657/9515291) This is a limitation on PHP's built-in server, not with Lumen

It works fine on a real web server, and then I use xampp as my local web server and access the route like this :

```
http://localhost/project-folder/public/url/api/v1.0
```